# Unity Inspector to show a list of functions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an events manager with many events listed

```
public class EventsManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static EventsManager current;

    private void Awake()
    {
        current = this;
    }

    public event Action onStartSession;
    public void StartExperience() { onStartSession?.Invoke(); }

    public event Action onPauseSession;
    public void PauseExperience() { onPauseSession?.Invoke(); }

    public event Action onResumeSession;
    public void ResumeExperience() { onResumeSession?.Invoke(); }
}
```

Is it possible to have a dropdown in the inspector for another object where I can select a function from the Events Manager?

I tries something like this but it didn't work

```
 public class BtnController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private AssetBundle assetBundle;

    public Func<EventsManager> trigger;

    ...
}
```

I cannot see the list of the public functions when I select a button which has the BtnController.

I am using an Events Trigger component already so that wouldn't solve the problem.

Comment: Use an `enum` in the Inspector and a `switch` / dictionary to decide which method to call? In general `Action` and `Func` are not serializable so they won't show up not will they be saved

Comment: @derHugo that was my alternative. I wasn't sure if I'm missing something. Maybe you can post an answer to the questions and I'll accept it for fullness on the topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in general the [Unity Serializer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) only serializes types that are [`[Serializable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute) which neither `Action` nor `Func` (or in general`delegate` are.

There are for sure a couple of alternatives.

The simplest would be to use an `enum` like

```
public enum EventType
{
    Start,
    Pause,
    Resume,
    // ...
}
```

and then attach listeners like e.g.

```
public void ListenTo(EventType type, Action callback)
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case EventType.Start:
            onStartSession += callback;
            break;
        case ....
    }
}
```

This `EventType` can now be exposed in the Inspector.

In general you should make those then

```
public event Action onStartSession;
```

so really only **this class** can invoke them.